# What is the difference between hostname suffixes .local and .lan?

Tags: networking, home-networking, lan, local, bonjour

Why do other computers on my home network sometimes resolve as xyz.local and other times as xyz.lan ?

I have a NAS device that shows up in Safari Bonjour bookmarks as xyz.local.  I've copied a direct link to a folder on the NAS into my bookmarks, sth like http://xyz.local/file/here.   Sometimes the xyz.local link does not work.  But when I replace the suffix .local with .lan, it works!  What is the difference between .local and .lan?

Comment: Playing around some more, I noticed that .local seems to work only when I am wired to the network with a cable, and .lan seems to work only when I am on wifi.  But if I use the IP address of the NAS box (in the same subnet), it works regardless of wired or wifi.

Answer (score 1):

The .local domain is usually used by [Zeroconf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf) [MDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS), which is a non-centralised DNS system where each machine announces the hostnames which they have. The .lan domain is probably used by your router, which runs a DNS server containing hostnames based on what machines declare when they [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP). If the .local hostname isn't working then something is wrong with MDNS (not being announced by remote machine, local resolver not working, etc.).